# Как заставить postgres использовать индекс в запросе?

Tags: postgresql

После переноса данных из postgres 10 в postgres 14 один и тот-же запрос стал выполняться в 2000 раз дольше.

PostgreSQL 10.7

Запрос выполняется 34ms, считается сумма транзакций за 5 минут. Тут все ок время устраивает.

```sql
SELECT sum(amount) sum, max(id) max 
FROM t_transaction 
WHERE id > (select max(id)-1000 from t_transaction) 
  AND (    created_at > '2021-12-13T16:15:00.000Z' 
       AND created_at <= '2021-12-13T16:20:00.000Z');
```

Перенесли БД в PostgreSQL 14.1 запрос тот-же, но выполняется уже 95421.923 ms, это очень долго. Видно что индекс не используется вообще.

```
explain analyze SELECT sum(amount) sum, max(id) max FROM t_transaction WHERE id > (select max(id)-1000 from t_transaction) AND (created_at > '2021-12-13T16:15:00.000Z' AND created_at <= '2021-12-13T16:20:00.000Z');
                                                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=8044103.05..8044103.06 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=95301.993..95307.927 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Result  (cost=0.60..0.61 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=378.417..378.420 rows=1 loops=1)
           InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
             ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..0.60 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.127..0.128 rows=1 loops=1)
                   ->  Index Only Scan Backward using t_transaction_pkey on t_transaction t_transaction_1  (cost=0.57..13762186.97 rows=483433280 width=4) (actual time=0.117..0.117 rows=1 loops=1)
                         Index Cond: (id IS NOT NULL)
                         Heap Fetches: 0
   ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..8044102.43 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=95301.967..95307.898 rows=0 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Params Evaluated: $1
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_transaction  (cost=0.00..8043102.33 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=94867.425..94867.425 rows=0 loops=3)
               Filter: ((id > $1) AND (created_at > '2021-12-13 16:15:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2021-12-13 16:20:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 161144405
 Planning Time: 49.518 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 21
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 4.629 ms, Inlining 421.424 ms, Optimization 96.794 ms, Emission 61.828 ms, Total 584.676 ms
 Execution Time: 95421.923 ms
(21 rows)
```

Пробовал делать ANALYZE t_transaction, результата не дало.

Индекс в таблице есть.

```
\d t_transaction
                                         Table "public.t_transaction"
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                  
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('t_transaction_id_seq'::regclass)
 from_id     | integer                     |           | not null | 
 to_id       | integer                     |           | not null | 
 amount      | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 type        | smallint                    |           | not null | 
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 external_id | integer                     |           | not null | 
 payload     | integer                     |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "t_transaction_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: А если подзапрос переместить в СТЕ? вроде 14-я версия избавилась от привычки материализовывать всё подряд...

Comment: Не очень умею в CTE, такой запрос длится также долго. explain analyze with regional_sales as ( select max(id)-1000 as id from t_transaction ) SELECT sum(amount) sum, max(id) max FROM t_transaction WHERE id > (select id from regional_sales) AND (created_at > '2021-12-13T16:15:00.000Z' AND created_at <= '2021-12-13T16:20:00.000Z');

Comment: `WITH cte AS (select max(id)-1000 max_id from t_transaction) SELECT sum(amount) sum, max(id) max 
FROM t_transaction CROSS JOIN cte WHERE id > max_id AND (created_at > '2021-12-13T16:15:00.000Z' AND created_at <= '2021-12-13T16:20:00.000Z');`

Comment: Тоже самое, 145583.375 ms  https://explain.tensor.ru/archive/explain/1ec4445cffaeef3d2a859b21497cd256:0:2021-12-14

Comment: Есть план с 10.7?

Comment: план с 10.7 https://explain.tensor.ru/archive/explain/39849f742d369320ed13682065b4cf15:0:2021-12-14

Comment: Оригинальный план показывает плохой cost и то, что 10.7 его выбирал, скорее говорит о том, что в 10.7 были проблемы, которых, очевидно, нет в 14. Обратите внимание на (очень плохую) оценку количества строк в `Bitmap Index Scan` по условию `id > $1`. Если эта же оценка сохранилась и в 14, то неудивительно, что выбран менее затратный (с точки зрения планировщика) план.

Comment: Я бы попробовал увеличить `statistics target` для индекса или добавить `limit 1000`, чтоб подсказать планировщику, что там не ожидается 2млн записей. Либо переписать запрос, чтоб заменить `max` - 1000 на явный `limit 1000`, что по идее будет лучшей, более явной подсказкой планировщику, что записей будет мало и лучше сначала по индексу сканировать, а уж потом отфильтровать среди 1000 записей те, которые не подходят по времени.

Comment: default_statistics_target=500 https://explain.tensor.ru/archive/explain/ea813e235eb823a4c70199a2de13386c:0:2021-12-15 не дал результата 
default_statistics_target=5000 https://explain.tensor.ru/archive/explain/6e83e6a380d5eb00188eb5461068d45e:0:2021-12-15 тоже результата нет
после всех изменений делал analyze t_transaction;
если убрать вложенный селект то план становиться нормальный и выполняется быстро
https://explain.tensor.ru/archive/explain/7222ffe1064ed1dc8ff652a00d1ca705:0:2021-12-15